# default network on surface pro 4 is loopback

Tags: linux-mint, network-interface, loopback

please look at this

```
amin@amin-Surface-Pro-4 ~ $ ssh 192.168.1.10 -p 1366
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.10 port 1366: No route to host
amin@amin-Surface-Pro-4 ~ $ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:102 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:102 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:7898 (7.8 KB)  TX bytes:7898 (7.8 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:5f:d3:51:bd:4c  
      inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::c8b2:45b5:e3de:1271/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1033 errors:0 dropped:6 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:841 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:110794 (110.7 KB)  TX bytes:78639 (78.6 KB)

amin@amin-Surface-Pro-4 ~ $
```

It is running on mint 18 sylvia! as u can see I tried ssh to a local VM with an ip in local range but there is no route to it!

And after `ifconfig` command it turns out that machine ip is set in `lo`not the `wlp2s0` that is the systems wifi related network!

question is: How can I change the default network to use wifi as its routing device?

**Update**

```
ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0  proto static  metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.37 metric 600
```

Comment: Next time, just copy and paste the text. No need to use an image. If you look at the output of `ifconfig`, you can see that your wireless interface (`wlp2s0`) has an ip of `192.168.1.2` assigned. If you want to use the wireless network for routing, you will need to set the local router as your default gateway.

Comment: Thank for the tip! but the main route is `lo`, so 192.168.1.10 is not in its range! look at the second line!

Comment: `lo` is an interface, not a route. The second line is just saying `ssh` cannot connect to `192.168.1.10` on port `1366`. If you are concerned with your routing, you can configure your route tables. But if you have your defaulat gw configured, that should be all you need for a simple wireless network. Your problem is more likely a firewall or sshd issue.

Comment: in terminal it just assumes that ip is 127.0.0.1 and net mask is 255.0.0.0 so I have no access to ips like 192.168.1.*!

Comment: Please add the output of `ip route show` to your question.

Comment: Dear Mark I updated the details!

Comment: and also when I use ssh without port I use: `ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.10 port 22: Connection refused`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem have been sorted out when I started `firewalld` on the guest operating system, and now it's working!!

Thanks